# Xcode Error with youtube api (api#channel) registration conflicts with GTLDriveChannel

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-data-api

My ViewController code is as follows

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <GTLServiceYouTube.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    GTLServiceYouTube *g=[[GTLServiceYouTube alloc] init];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

For the above code i receive the following error.

> GTLDriveChannel (api#channel) registration conflicts with
>   GTLCalendarChannel GTLPlusDomainsAcl (plus#acl) registration conflicts
>   with GTLPlusAcl GTLPlusDomainsActivity (plus#activity) registration
>   conflicts with GTLPlusActivity GTLPlusDomainsActivityFeed
>   (plus#activityFeed) registration conflicts with GTLPlusActivityFeed
>   GTLPlusDomainsComment (plus#comment) registration conflicts with
>   GTLPlusComment GTLPlusDomainsCommentFeed (plus#commentFeed)
>   registration conflicts with GTLPlusCommentFeed GTLPlusPeopleFeed
>   (plus#peopleFeed) registration conflicts with GTLPlusDomainsPeopleFeed
>   GTLPlusPerson (plus#person) registration conflicts with
>   GTLPlusDomainsPerson GTLPlusPlace (plus#place) registration conflicts
>   with GTLPlusDomainsPlace GTLStorageChannel (api#channel) registration
>   conflicts with GTLDriveChannel

My podfile configuration is listed below

```
target 'VideoApp', :exclusive => true do
pod "youtube-ios-player-helper", "~> 0.1"
pod 'Google-API-Client'
end
```

Nothing helpful here too. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-api-objectivec-client/cW2TIBZ7mwA

In the developer console two apis are enabled.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I already implemented my own wrapper for YouTube Data API, you can use it if you wish, it is simple :)

https://github.com/muhammadbassio/YouTubeAPI3-Objective-C-wrapper